# Write test class for apex(salesforce)

Tags: salesforce, apex

I write code for Apex trigger, now i need to test him. Can u help me?
here is the code:

```
public with sharing class Sharing_Sales {
public static void SharingRelatedOrdersAndAccount(List<Sales_Rep_Assignment__c> triggerNew, 
        Map<Id, Sales_Rep_Assignment__c> oldMap){
    List<Order> relatedOrders = new List<Order>();
    List<Sales_Rep_Assignment__c> activeAssignments = new List<Sales_Rep_Assignment__c>();
    Set<Id> accIds = new Set<Id>();
    Set<Id> salesRepsIds = new Set<Id>();
    Map<Id, List<Order>> ordersByAccountId = new Map<Id, List<Order>>();

    for(Sales_Rep_Assignment__c sar: triggerNew){
        if(sar.Active__c == true && (oldMap.get(sar.id).Active__c == false || oldMap == null)) {
            activeAssignments.add(sar);
            salesRepsIds.add(sar.Sales_Reps__c);
            accIds.add(sar.Account__c);
    }

    for(Order ord : [SELECT Id, AccountId FROM Order WHERE AccountId IN :accIds]) {
        if (!ordersByAccountId.containsKey(ord.AccountId)) {
            ordersByAccountId.put(ord.AccountId, new List<Order>());
        }
        ordersByAccountId.get(ord.AccountId).add(ord);
    }
    
    List<OrderShare> sharingRecords = new List<OrderShare>();
    for (Sales_Rep_Assignment__c srs : activeAssignments) {
        for (Order ord : ordersByAccountId.get(srs.Account__c)) {
            OrderShare sharingorderrecord = new OrderShare();
            sharingorderrecord.OrderId = ord.Id;
            sharingorderrecord.OrderAccessLevel = 'Edit';
            sharingorderrecord.UserOrGroupId = 'Sales_Rep__c';
            sharingorderrecord.RowCause = 'Manual';

            sharingRecords.add(sharingorderrecord);
        }
        if(!sharingRecords.IsEmpty()){
            insert sharingRecords;
        }
    }
 }  
} 
public static void Sharingorderandaccountisdelete(List<Sales_Rep_Assignment__c> triggerNew, 
List<Order> relatedOrders,
Map<id, Sales_Rep_Assignment__c> oldMap){
    List<Sales_Rep_Assignment__c> falseAssignments = new List<Sales_Rep_Assignment__c>();
    Set<Id> accIds = new Set<Id>();
    Set<Id> salesRepsIds = new Set<Id>();
    Map<Id, List<Order>> ordersByAccountId = new Map<Id, List<Order>>();
    for(Sales_Rep_Assignment__c sar: triggerNew){
        if(sar.Active__c == false && oldMap.get(sar.id).Active__c == true || triggerNew == null){
            falseAssignments.add(sar);
            salesRepsIds.add(sar.Sales_Reps__c);
            accIds.add(sar.Account__c);
        }
    }
    List<OrderShare> sharingDeletedOrder = new List<OrderShare>();
    for(Order ord : [SELECT Id, AccountId FROM Order WHERE AccountId IN :accIds]) {
        if (!ordersByAccountId.containsKey(ord.AccountId)) {
            ordersByAccountId.put(ord.AccountId, new List<Order>());
        }
        for(OrderShare sharingRecords: [SELECT Id FROM OrderShare WHERE Id =: ord.id AND UserOrGroupId IN :salesRepsIds]){
            sharingDeletedOrder.add(sharingRecords);
        }    
    }
    delete sharingDeletedOrder;
```

}
}`

deskp of task Use
Apex Trigger to share Account and related Orders to Sales Rep when new Sales Rep Assignment is created.
When Sales Rep Assignment record is deleted or set to Active = false Sales Rep should not have edit access to account and related orders anymore, if Active is set back to true – share records again.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a test class. Here you will find some guidance:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_qs_test.htm

After you worked it through and wrote a test class, we can help with problems.